# ASPX Page XSLT and Master Page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASPX page rendered with XSLT. I also have a master page which has the basic page layout. When I see the page in the browser it is not displaying the page format from the master page.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you rendering the XSLT on the server side or client side?  Also make sure your CSS files are referenced correctly.
Can you please post some code

Comment: I am creating a prototype. Where I need like a tree structure which opens up a Grid (html table) the existing code is in ASP ( remaining pages 10 ASP and 6 ASPX pages.) So I started using a ASPX page and I was able to achieve the tree like struture and the Grid. They previously have a master page and this aspx page isn't able to read the master page. Is it any clearer?

Comment: If your master page is not showing on your aspx page then... Do a create new ASPX page w/ Master Page and then select the master page.  It will generate a aspx page which uses the selected master page.  Use this code (template) to build your aspx page.

Comment: I created a default.aspx file and selected the master page. Without making any changes I browsed to default.aspx and it still doesn't display the content from the master pages.

Comment: @kalls: This means that the problem isn't due to XSLT at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your XSLT is doing some XML transformation and then doing a Response.Write to send the page to the browser? If so, you're bypassing all the reasons of using an aspx page in the first place. If your code-behind is doing any Response.Write you should be using the more lightweight ashx handler instead of the heavier aspx page (heavier because it automatically takes care of things like masterpages).

When I've done this sort of thing in the past, I basically re-created a masterpage system using XSLT templates like so: http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xslapplytemplates.php